# How to get correct number of sub elements in ordered dictionary?

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I have the following 2 ordered dictionaries(that are the output from previous steps) that are similar, the only difference is that `dict1` has only one node named `GROUP` and `dict2` has two (0 and 1 like in image)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dict1 = OrderedDict([('CATALOG', 
            OrderedDict([('GROUP', 
                OrderedDict([
                    ('ZONE', '4'), 
                    ('LIGHT', 'Mostly Shady'), 
                    ('PLANT', [
                        OrderedDict([
                            ('COMMON', 'Bloodroot'), 
                            ('BOTANICAL', 'Sanguinaria canadensis')]), 
                        OrderedDict([
                            ('COMMON', 'Columbine'), 
                            ('BOTANICAL', 'Aquilegia canadensis')])])]))]))])
                            
dict2 = OrderedDict([('CATALOG', 
            OrderedDict([('GROUP', [
                OrderedDict([
                    ('ZONE', '3'), 
                    ('LIGHT', 'Mostly Shady'), 
                    ('PLANT', [
                        OrderedDict([
                            ('COMMON', "Dutchman's-Breeches"), 
                            ('BOTANICAL', 'Dicentra cucullaria')]), 
                        OrderedDict([
                            ('COMMON', 'Ginger, Wild'), 
                            ('BOTANICAL', 'Asarum canadense')])])]), 
                OrderedDict([
                    ('ZONE', '4'), 
                    ('LIGHT', 'Mostly Sunny'), 
                    ('PLANT', [
                        OrderedDict([
                            ('COMMON', 'Marsh Marigold'), 
                            ('BOTANICAL', 'Caltha palustris')]), 
                        OrderedDict([
                            ('COMMON', 'Cowslip'), 
                            ('BOTANICAL', 'Caltha palustris')])])])])]))])
```

Where the structure is like this:
[image]

I'm having issues in identify how many groups have each dictionary and my attempts like below, shows correct number of groups for `dict2` that are 2, but for `dict1` shows as answer 3 when there is only one group. And if I use a loop to print each group, for `dict2` prints 2 orderedDict that is correct, but for `dict1` prints other subnodes that are not `GROUP`. What I'm doing wrong.

```
>>> len(dict1['CATALOG']['GROUP'])
3
>>> len(dict2['CATALOG']['GROUP'])
2
>>> dict1['CATALOG']['GROUP'][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 0
>>>
>>> dict2['CATALOG']['GROUP'][0]
OrderedDict([('ZONE', '3'), ('LIGHT', 'Mostly Shady')...
>>>
>>> dict2['CATALOG']['GROUP'][1]                     ...
OrderedDict([('ZONE', '4'), ('LIGHT', 'Mostly Sunny')...
>>>                                                  ...
>>> for group in dict1['CATALOG']['GROUP']:          
...  print(group)                                    
...                                                  
ZONE                                                 
LIGHT                                                
PLANT                                                
>>> for group in dict2['CATALOG']['GROUP']:          
...  print(group)                                    
...                                                  
OrderedDict([('ZONE', '3'), ('LIGHT', 'Mostly Shady')...
OrderedDict([('ZONE', '4'), ('LIGHT', 'Mostly Sunny')...
```

Comment: `dict1['CATALOG']['GROUP']` is a dictionary with 3 keys, `dict2['CATALOG']['GROUP']` is a list with two elements.

Comment: BTW, since Python 3.6, regular dictionaries remember their order, so you don't need to use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So, I need to identify when dictionary has only keys (would be one `GROUP`) and when is a listt with more than one element (that would indicate more than one `GROUP`). I use OrderedDict because is the output given by a previous step not controlled by me.

Comment: @GerCas Do you want to count the sub elements in the dictionary? Or just identify if the object is a list or not?

Comment: @Elan-R I want to know how many nodes `GROUP` are inside the dictionary. With the help or @Barmar I understood that to do that I need to know first if `GROUP` is a list or a dictionary. After knowing that, I can count the number of nodes named `GROUP`. If it is a dict length =1, if it is a list lenght = number of elements in that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether `dictX['CATALOG']['GROUP']` is a list or not. If it's not a list, the length is 1.

```
group1_len = len(dict1['CATALOG']['GROUP']) if isinstance(dict1['CATALOG']['GROUP'], list) else 1
group2_len = len(dict2['CATALOG']['GROUP']) if isinstance(dict2['CATALOG']['GROUP'], list) else 1
```

It would probably make all your further processing if you wrapped the dictionary in a list first. Then both dictionaries will have similar structure and you won't need to keep using conditions.

```
for d in (dict1, dict2):
    if not isinstance(d['CATALOG']['GROUP'], list):
        d['CATALOG']['GROUP'] = [d['CATALOG']['GROUP']]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but `dict1` and `dict2` are generated for the same previous process. a library called `xmltodict` that takes input from xml files. It seems that when file only has one `GROUP`, generates dictionary value as an OrderedDict, not a list of OrderedDicts like in `dict1`

Comment: You can use `isinstance()` to test if it's a dictionary or list. If it's a dictionary, then there's just one of them.

Comment: Excellent. That seems to work for me, I've tried testing if is a list and for `dict1` gives `false` and for `dict2` gives `true`. `>>> isinstance(dict1['CATALOG']['GROUP'], list)
False
>>> isinstance(dict2['CATALOG']['GROUP'], list)
True`

Comment: Excellent!!! Then you first `fix` the structure of dictionary and then `len(dictX['CATALOG']['GROUP'])` will work for any kind of dictionary with one or more groups.

Answer (score 1):

The length you're getting for your `dict1` are the keys themselves. If we know that this object is a `Dict` type we can do some work with a helper method.

You can do some type checking in the beginning to determine the shape of the object. This would tell you if the underlying shape is a `Dict` (aka, 1 item) vs. a `List` (aka, multiple).

```py
# something with 1 item, dict rendering
dict1 = {...}

# something with 2 items, list rendering
dict2 = {...}

# helper method
def checkShape(dict):
    length = 0
    if isinstance(dict['CATALOG']['GROUP'], dict):
        # we know len is 1
        length = 1
    else:
        # we know len is >1
        length = len(dict['CATALOG']['GROUP'])
    return length
```

Comment: Excellent!, your solution works fine too. I only change the argument to `dictX` since get error using only `dict` because is confused with element `type` expected in `isinstance(dictX,dict)`. Thanks so much